# Format a string for cents only in C#

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a dollar amount, 23.15. I want to format it so that I can return just .15 or 15 as I want to place just the cents in an html `<sup>` tag.

To return dollars only, I used `{0:C0}` or without the $ sign `{0:N0}`

**Edit:** Apparently `{0:C0}` and `{0:N0}` will not work for me as they round to a whole number :(

Comment: Hove you tried a format string like {.00} ? I dont have VS open so I can't test, but might work

Comment: @Andrey, just tried that, returns the whole number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need string with html tags you can use something like this:

```
 var decimalValue = 23.15m;
 string value2 = decimalValue.ToString("$ #.<sup>##</sup>"); //$ 23.<sup>15</sup>
```

Also if you want amount with cents instead of

```
var value =  String.Format("{0:C0}", decimalValue); // $23
```

use

```
 var value =  String.Format("{0:C2}", decimalValue); // $23.15
```

Zero after 'C' in '{0:C0}' format means number of signs after point.

Comment: the `{0:C}` specifier returns `$123.46` for me for an input of `123.4567M` - that doesn't sound like what he wants

Comment: It's answer to another question: 'Edit: Apparently {0:C0} and {0:N0} will not work for me as they round to a whole number :('

Comment: I used your first example, :C0 doesn't show cents, but it also rounds the dollar amount. Also, in my case I won't ever need to have an amount that is in the thousands, but if I did how could I make the 1st example do it automatically?

Comment: @nick if you want amount with cents use {0:C2} if you want amout with cents in sup tag use: decimalValue.ToString("$ #.<sup>##</sup>");

Answer (score 0):

Not the mainstream way but will work :)

```
dollarAmount - Math.Floor(dollarAmount)
```

will get you cents (in your sample will get .15).

Comment: that's one way to do it, I would rather use a format operator if there is one, as it is cleaner.

Comment: Yup, there should be some format string for that, I just am not too good at remembering those, so sometimes I just use algebra instead :)

Answer (score 0):

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

```
    {

        double Num;
        // declaring "Num" as a double

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter dollar and cents amount\nExample: 4.52");
        //This bit of code informs the user what type of information you want from them

        Num = double.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
        //assigns "Num" to the users input and sets the user input as numerical value and stores it in the temporary memory

        Console.WriteLine("You have {1} dollars and {2} cents from {0:c}.", Num, WhyAreWeDoingThis(ref Num), Num);
        //returns the values requested and sends "Num" through the program to separate dollars from cents.
        //first: off in{0:c} it takes the original user input and gives it the dollar sign$ due to the additional code to the left of the zero as shown {0:c}
        //second: "Num" is sent to the WhyAreWeDoingThis Method through the reference method "ref" where the dollar amount is separated from the cent amount
        //*Note* this will only return the dollar amount not the cents*
        //Third: the second "Num" referred to at this point is only the remaining cents from the total money amount. 
        //*Note* this is because the program is moving "Num" around as a stored value from function to function not grabbing the users original input every time.

        Console.ReadLine();
        //this keeps the program open

    }
    static int WhyAreWeDoingThis(ref double A)
        // reference method
        //*Note* it is set as a "static int" and (ref double)

    {
        int dd = (int)A;
        //this turn the double into a temporary integer by type casting for this one operation only.
        A = A % dd;
        //Separates the dollars from the cents leaving only the cents in the "Num" value through the Modulus Operand.
        return dd;
        //returns the dollar amount.
    }
}
```

Comment: please post detailed explanation with code, its not understandable right now.